# Update javascript parent variable from a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

In node.js I need to collect some data across multiple callbacks and store them in one object. I tried the following code, but the collected data is not saved in the initialized variable. Can you pls help what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
for (var x in data) {
    var status = {items: []};

    for (var y in x) {
        do_something(y, function (err, res) {
            again_do_something(res, function(err, result) {
                status.items.push({key: result});
            });
         });
     }

     console.log(status); //Here I got only {items: []}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
console.log(status);
```

will be getting executed before the callback function getting executed. Thats why you are seeing empty.

One easy way to solve this common problem is to use [async library's concat method](https://github.com/caolan/async#concatarr-iterator-callback).

Comment: Thanks! I've missed that. But then how can I track down when has the last callback been executed so I can pass the collected data forward?

Comment: @filo891 Updated my answer with async library solution. Please check.